GORM many2many Association Replace not working as expected
I have a GO application using GIN and GORM. I want to create a Roles + Capabilities database. A role can have multiple capabilities and a capability can be in multiple roles. I created the following two models:
package models

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Capability struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name        string `gorm:"column:name;size:100;type:string"`
    Description string `gorm:"column:description;type:string"`
}

func (Capability) TableName() string {
    return "capabilities"
}

package models

import (
    "fmt"

    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Role struct {
    gorm.Model

    ID             string       `gorm:"primarykey;type:string;column:id"`
    Name           string       `gorm:"type:string;column:name"`
    OrganizationID uint         `gorm:"column:organization_id;type:uint"`
    Capabilities   []Capability `gorm:"many2many:org_role_capability;"`
}

func (Role) TableName() string {
    return "roles"
}

func CreateNewOrganizationRoleId(organizationId uint, roleName string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s-%d", roleName, organizationId)
}

func CapabilityRoleAssociationName() string {
    return "Capabilities"
}


I am able to insert and get the roles, and the table org_role_capability updates correctly in insert case, but when I try to modify using this code, I run into an error:
func ModifyRole(db *gorm.DB, roleName string, capabilities []string, context *gin.Context) (*models.NewRole, error) {
    var capabilityEntities []models.Capability
    var tempRole models.NewRole

    db.Where("name IN ?", capabilities).Find(&capabilityEntities)
    organization, _ := contextUtils.GetDetailsFromRequestContext(context)

    err := db.Transaction(func(transaction *gorm.DB) error {
        tempRole := models.NewRole{
            ID: models.CreateNewOrganizationRoleId(organization.ID, roleName),
        }

        return transaction.Model(
            &tempRole,
        ).Where(
            &tempRole,
        ).Association(
            models.CapabilityRoleAssociationName(),
        ).Replace(
            capabilityEntities,
        )
    })

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &tempRole, nil
}

The error:
2024/06/19 14:50:26 /workspace/backend/services/rolesServices.go:115 mssql: Invalid column name 'id'.
[1.967ms] [rows:0] DELETE FROM "org_role_capability" WHERE "org_role_capability"."id" = 'EXECUTIVE-2' AND "org_role_capability"."new_role_id" = 'EXECUTIVE-2' AND "org_role_capability"."capability_id" <> 3
[GIN] 2024/06/19 - 14:50:26 | 500 |   15.345708ms |       127.0.0.1 | PUT      "/api/roles"
Error #01: mssql: Invalid column name 'id'.

Here is the DDL for org_role_capability:
CREATE TABLE "org_role_capability"
  (
     "role_primary_id" NVARCHAR(256),
     "capability_id"   BIGINT,
     PRIMARY KEY ("role_id", "capability_id"),
     CONSTRAINT "fk_org_role_capability_role" FOREIGN KEY ("role_id")
     REFERENCES "roles"("id"),
     CONSTRAINT "fk_org_role_capability_capability" FOREIGN KEY ("capability_id"
     ) REFERENCES "capabilities"("id")
  ) 

I think the query being executed is correct but why is it asserting id column from org_role_capability model which does not even exist.
I tried updating and adding foreignKeys etc. but I don't really understand and nothing works.

Please Edit your question to include the DDL of the actual org_role_capability table from the database.

@AlwaysLearning added the DDL.
